# Python: How should I reformat this short code block?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python. Have been studying it with courses on udacity and now I am trying to do things to learn further more.

I've created this short code block:

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
for e in a_list:
    list_a.append(e['a'])
    list_b.append(e['b'])
list_b = set(list_b)
```

(list_a as well should not contain duplicates but it won't be attempted in first place so no strict need of making it a set as well unless it makes the code better looking and easier to go through)

After looking at this code of mine, it does not seem elegant or Pythonic enough.

My question is, how should I reformat this? I would like to learn the good and right way of doing things.

> My goal here is to go through a list called a_list, which contains
>   dictionaries as its items. Then for each item in the dictionary, add
>   the value of key 'a' to a new list called list_a, and do the same for
>   key 'b'. However list of key 'b' should be a set and strictly not to
>   contain any duplicates.

Thank you.

Comment: `e['a']` seems strange -- that makes it look like the keys in `a_dictionary` are themselves dictionaries, which they can't be.  [They could be something else supporting that kind of access, I guess.]

Comment: Yes, you need to give a sample of what `a_dictionary` looks like.

Comment: I am sorry, those were my mistakes. After editing the code blocks to remove English words to not to confuse anyone, I mistakenly did a cmd+v which overrode them. there is only list_a and list_b

Comment: why don't you try to explain what you are trying to accomplish. it is a bit hard to make that out from the code you posted.

Comment: DSM already noted the same thing - dictionary keys (which is what `e` will contain when iterating over a dict) can't themselves be dictionaries, so `e['a']` would not work. What is `a_dictionary`, and what do you want `list_a` and `list_b` to contain?

Comment: I apologize to everyone. I am very sorry. Updated the question, fixed all the mistakes.

Comment: your code is fine but don't use list_b for storing a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this does iterate over `a_list` twice, you can rewrite it like this:

```
list_a = [e['a'] for e in a_list]
set_b = {e['b'] for e in a_list}
```

assuming Python 2.7 or later.

I've chosen the name `set_b` instead of `list_b` since we're doing a set comprehension, not a list comprehension in the second line.

If you want to iterate over `a_list` only once, then you can at least skip one list creation:

```
list_a = []
set_b = set()
for e in a_list:
    list_a.append(e['a'])
    set_b.add(e['b'])
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. For your answer and patience. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

@TimPietzcker gave a fine solution.  I should mention though that rather than storing data in variable names like `list_a` and `list_b` -- what would you do if you if you had nine keys you wanted to pull out? -- I think it's more pythonic to use another dictionary (Python 2.7+):

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 2, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
>>> keep = ('a', 'b')
>>> by_key = {k: {d[k] for d in list_of_dicts} for k in keep}
>>> by_key
{'a': set([1, 2]), 'b': set([10, 20])}
```

and then instead of `list_a`, you'd use

```
>>> by_key['a']
set([1, 2])
```

Comment: This is an excellent thing. Thank you for sharing it. I will keep it in mind and use it. Superb!